# .htaccess Redirecting to a file messes the folder name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have no clue how to use .htaccess but so far I got to a simple redirect.

```
Redirect /global-awards http://religiousfreedomandbusiness.org/global-awards.html
```

The problem is that I have a folder named /global-awards/ 
so when I try to go to global-awards/finalist.html the browser turns the name of the folder to /global-awards`.html`/finalist.html

Edit:
code with multiview:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

Redirect /global-awards http://religiousfreedomandbusiness.org/global-awards.html

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you just want to serve `/global-awards.html` when browser shows `/global-awards` in URL?

Comment: that was what i wanted in the first place, but because I didn't find that option, I just did the redirect.
What I am doing is trying to add a few pages to a WordPress website. There is a link for /global-awards, but for some reason, it doesn't get /global-awards.html. So I just did the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` i.e. `Redirect` directive with `mod_rewrite` rules. Have it like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^global-awards/?$ /global-awards.html [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Options -MultiViews
```

in top of your htaccess, please tell me if not working.

Comment: Thanks Abhishk,but it didn't really worked.
Im going to update the question with the code from the file.